# Approximation Notations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $A\approx B$ and $B=C$.

Isn't it incorrect for some textbooks to write them together like $A\approx B=C$ rather than $A\approx B\approx C$?

Because

$A$

$\approx B$

$=C$

is essentially saying $A=C$ if we cut the middle-man, which is false!

Another example:

$1$

$=0.5+0.5$

$=2-1$

$=1$

Cut out the middle derivations and we get $1=1$ which is true.

Comment: It depends, I would write $0.99 \approx 1 = {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}$. The first is an approximation, the rest exact.

Comment: Under most interpretations of the $\approx$ symbol, we would have if $A\approx B$ that it should be true regardless of the representation of $B$.  I.e. if $A\approx B$ and $B=C$ that it should *also* be true that $A\approx C$.  This is different than saying that $A=C$ like you seem to suggest.

Comment: As for if $A\approx B$ and $B\approx C$, if your "$\approx$" happens to be an equivalence relation, then it will also be true that $A\approx C$ (*as is the case with the prototypical equivalence relation $=$*), however in the event that it is not an equivalence relation this is not necessarily true.  For example, if $x\approx y$ means "$x$ and $y$ are within $1$ distance from eachother", then you would have $0.5\approx 1.2$ and you would have $1.2\approx 1.8$ but $0.5\not\approx 1.8$

Comment: Take for additional example the usage of $<$ rather than $\approx$.  It is commonplace to write statements like $a<b\leq c = d$, to which this implies that $a<d$, and does *not* imply that $a=d$ (*in fact it directly implies that $a\neq d$*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given $A≈B$ and $B=C$.
>
> Isn't it incorrect for some textbooks to write them together like $A≈B=C$ rather than $A≈B≈C$?

No, the textbooks are correct.

Note that the combined statement $A≈B=C$ means $A≈B$ and $B=C$ which is what you'd like to claim.

On the other hand $A≈B≈C$ means $A≈B$ and $B≈C$ which is not what you'd like to claim because it does not imply the equality of $B$ and $C$ as it was intended.

Comment: Hmmmmmm. I've been doing it all wrong for all these years!